# How to interpret odds of a logistic model using cbind()

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cbind

I've computed a logistic mixed-effects model in R to investigate the number of words people were able to identify correctly in a linguistic experiment. The code reads as follows:

```
glmer(cbind(nr_corr, maximum - nr_corr) ~ (predictor1 | SUBJECT) + predictor1 +  predictor2 + predictor1:predictor2, dataMelt, family = binomial)
```

nr_corr is the number of correctly identified words, the maximum denotes the highest possible number (6 in this case).

So far, I've worked with models where the dependent variable was Bernoulli-distributed, i.e. there were only two options: success (1) and failure (0). I was able to interpret the odds which I computed on the basis of the model coefficients accordingly. The dependant variable in the model was obviously not coded as `(cbind(nr_corr, maximum - nr_corr)` then.

Now I'm not sure how to interpret the coefficients/odds of the model that uses cbind() for the dependent variable - obviously, there are more possibilities than success and failure here, since the n of trials is not 1, but 6. That is, I'm not sure what exactly the coefficients in the model summary and the odds computed on the basis of them denote (odds for correctly identifying 1 word out of 6? 2 out of 6? etc). I'd be very grateful for any hints and advice!

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? It's impossible to evaluate what `cbind(nr_corr, maximum - nr_corr)` is otherwise. Posting your output would also be very helpful, especially given that you want use to interpret the resultant coeffiicients and odds. This is also more of a stats question than coding since the core of this question is 'interpret the coefficients and odds' - it better belongs at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can check BenBolker's answer below.. Basically, when you the response in the matrix, you are modeling the log odds ratio between nr_corr , maximum - nr_corr, i.e success is nr_corr, failure is maximum - nr_corr

Comment: @StupidWolf: thank you. But both nr_corr and maximum-nr_corr can be a value between 0 and 6. So I have trouble understanding what exactly the per-trial probability is supposed to be...

Comment: @MBorg: Thanks for letting me know, I will post stat-related questions there in the future :)!

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients are the log-odds-ratios (or equivalently differences in log-odds, or differences in logit(prob)) of the **per-trial** probability.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ben! So does that mean that the coefficients/log-odds-ratios again relate to the two options success (1) and failure (0)? Is the per-trial probability like an 'average' probability of being the option x rather than option y? I'm sorry for asking, but I'm not familiar with the term 'per-trial probability'. I've looked it up and found a passage on it in your book "Ecological Models and Data in R", but being new to statistical modelling and not at all a Maths expert, I have trouble grasping the concept...